# Swift UI elements in IOS app not getting any closer to each other

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

In my Swift UI app, there are these large spacings between elements in the app and I can't seem to get them to be closer after the newest X-code release.

[Here is what the broken look is...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGjxZ.png)

[Here is what it looked like before...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGyBy.jpg)

Here is the code for the first 4 buttons:

```
HStack {
                Text("Toggle between colors")
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    colorToggleLogic()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Color")
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 75)
                        .padding(5)
                        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.blue, Color.gray]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }).offset(x: -5, y: 0)
            }.foregroundColor(.black)
            
            
            
            // zero toggle button
            HStack {
                Text("Enable/Disable Zeros in division")
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    if viewModel.zeroToggle == false {
                        viewModel.zeroToggle = true
                        zeroToggleName = "Enabled"
                        zeroToggleColor = .green
                    }
                    else {
                        viewModel.zeroToggle = false
                        zeroToggleName = "Disabled"
                        zeroToggleColor = .red
                        
                    }
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(self.viewModel.zeroToggle, forKey: "zeroToggle")
                }, label: {
                    Text(zeroToggleName)
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 75)
                        .padding(5)
                        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(zeroToggleColor), Color.gray]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
                        .background(Color(zeroToggleColor))
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }).offset(x: -5, y: 0)
            }.offset(x: 0, y: 5)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            
            // purchase full version
            HStack {
                Text("Purchase full version")
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                Spacer()
                NavigationLink(destination:
                                ParentalGate()
                ) {
                    Text("Purchase")
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 75)
                        .padding(5)
                        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.black, Color.gray]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
                        .background(Color(.black))
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                .offset(x: -5, y: 0)
```

Comment: Can you include a [mre]? The code you've included includes a bunch of types/variables that no one has access to and can't compile. And, I'm assuming that not only is it in the `body` property of a `View`, but it's *probably* within another element (like a `ScrollView`, `VStack`, etc) that is likely very important to solving this issue.

Comment: @jnpdx I will try to, thanks for the advice. FYI, it's not a scrolly view and it is simply a VStack.

Comment: Try `VStack(spacing: 0)`

Comment: @jnpdx That solved it thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put

`VStack(spacing:0)`

Under the main VStack. It will solve the issue.